# Automatically add more content/ field (Wordpress)

Tags: html, css, wordpress, field

I'm working on a website in Wordpress with my own theme/ template. Now I've the following question:

How can I put some code to my CSS or HTML, so the content/ field will add a longer field to the page?
My content design consists of rounded corners, so when more content/ text is added than fits, the extra field that appears must have rounded corners too. For example and clarity I added an image:

[image]

I need some code for the extra content (the one in the image with the dotted lines.)
The field is white coloured with some little shadow on the left side.

Thanks in advance! Kim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excuse me if I haven't understood what you're trying to achieve, but do you need anything more complicated than the CSS min-height property?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your question is exactly, but there's no reason why you shouldn't have rounded corners only at the top, or only at the bottom, of an element.

See http://borderradius.com/ for a utility which creates borders for you, for instance:

```
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px;-
border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
```

has rounded corners at the bottom and not at the top.